# Approximate factors in an average calculation

Tags: java, algorithm, math, weighted-average

here is what I want to do:
I have an double[] of size N  (N will not be larger than 500 but different applications of this program will have different Ns). I now want to find out what combinations I can achieve a given average with. For example:

The number I look for is 3. The double array has only 2 items in it {6,2}

the program should loop through and tell me that 1x[0] and 3x[1] = 6+2+2+2 / 4 = 3  is the easiest way to get to this. I also want to limit these factors to a maximum of say 10,000 (i.e. it can be a maximum of 10,000[0]+10,000[1])

I was experimenting with nested while loops but couldn't get it to work. A jumpstart please?

thanks

edit: here is what I have so far. it is working for the two given combinations but would be prohibitively convoluted to implement due to it requiring one for loop for each factor.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] returns = {6,2};
    double givenReturn = 3;
    double maxStock = 5000;
    double calcReturn = 0;


    for (int a = 0; a < maxStock && (givenReturn != calcReturn); a++) {//first level

        for (int b = 0; b < maxStock && (givenReturn != calcReturn); b++) {//second level

            calcReturn = (a*returns[0]+b*returns[1])/(a+b);
            if(calcReturn == givenReturn){
                System.out.println(a+" "+b);
                break;
            }
        }

    }



}

}
```

the program successfully prints: "1 3".

How can I make the program work with say an array of ten different returns?

Comment: Not sure if it is the most efficient way, but you could look for 1 number that is 3, or 2 numbers whose sum is 6, or 3 numbers whose sum is 9, ... or N numbers whose sum is 3xN. In each case the average will be 3. There are several questions on SO about solving the sum problem, such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331488/finding-the-minimal-set-that-sum-to-a-given-number-in-an-array-of-integers

Comment: Thanks, however the question you linked isn't quite what i was looking for. It went in the general direction but my problem is not dealing with a minimum subset summation but rather a minimum subset average calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference sake, your problem put mathematically:

```
Given an integer T and a vector c (|c| <= 500), solve for vector a and integer b:
(all numbers are non-negative integers)
a0.c0 + a1.c1 + a2.c2 + ... = T.b
a0 + a1 + a2 + ... = b
each ai <= 10000
b > 0
Additional constraint: minimize b
```

For your example:

`c` is {6,2}, `T` is 3, `a` comes to {1, 3} and `b` comes to 4.

It feels like there should be a [mathematical](https://math.stackexchange.com/) way to solve it (though I doubt there is).

Brute force will be way too slow. For 500 types up to 10000 occurrences each, we're talking about 500^10000, which is ... a lot.

I'm thinking [CSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) or [hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing).

Hill climbing is easy enough to implement - you will basically just start with some random selection of elements, then add and remove elements to get closer to the target.

[The wiki page on integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) has a bit of useful information.

Comment: thanks, ill look into that. It was the starting point I needed. Also I will be running this on a university high performance computer system so it should spit things out fast :)